# Dynamic code compilation fails when running tests with Sbt

Tags: java, scala, sbt, javac

I have a scala test that dynamically generates a java source code and compiles it at runtime. It works perfectly when I run tests in IDE (IntelliJ), but fails when using `sbt test`.

The main difference is when running in IDE my test class, third party classes (jars), and `com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool` class are loaded by `jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader`. When running in sbt, my test class, third party classes (jars) are loaded using `sbt.internal.LayeredClassLoader`, but `com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool` is still loaded by `jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader`, thus `JavacTool` fails to compile a generated code b/c thrid party classes cannot be found (parent class loader doesn't have access to child's classes). Is possible to overcome this *issue*?

UPDATE: I set `-cp` using the code below:

```java
List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();
optionList.add("-cp");
optionList.add(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

When running in IDE `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` returns the whole classpath including third-party jars, however, when running from Sbt there is only one jar in classpath: `C:\Users\PliashkouRaman\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2022.1\plugins\Scala\launcher\sbt-launch.jar`

I hardcoded a list of jars and now the test is passing.

Comment: Maybe this helps?
https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/In-Process-Classloaders.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by appending `fullClasspath` to `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`

sbt:

```scala
Test / testOptions += Tests.Setup(() => {
      val jars = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[String]
      (Runtime / fullClasspath).value.foreach { e =>
        jars += e.data.getAbsolutePath
      }
      jars += System.getProperty("java.class.path")
      val classpath = jars.mkString(":")
      System.setProperty("java.class.path", classpath)
      println(classpath)
    })
```

UPDATE:

classpath delimiter is OS specific

`:` Linux

`;` Win